# Как узнать есть ли в строке из множества чисел какое-то определенное число?

Tags: php

У наc есть строка, состоящая из нескольких чисел через запятую:

```
$allNam = '12,2,41,51,8,53';
```

Нужно найти в переменной $allNam число 51 и если оно там есть вывести True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 вариант

```
function search($str, $search) {
    return false !== stripos($str, $search);
}

$allNam = '12,2,41,51,8,53';
$result = search($allNam, 51);
```

2 вариант

```
$allNam = '12,2,41,51,8,53';
$result = in_array(51, explode(',', $allNam));
```